# Drag and Drop Wpf DataGrid to DataGrid

Tags: wpf

I can't find any working code for C# WPF window project that supports drag and drop object from one DataGrid to another DataGrid. Does anyone have one?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2534040/wpf-drag-and-drop-to-datagrid?rq=1

Comment: none of them helped.. do you have any source code that is closed to what i described?